# my Clion2022 always crashes for no reason，and this is its report

Tags: visual-studio, sdk, crash, clion, crash-reports

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x0000000016ab2bd6, pid=23924, tid=14792
#
# JRE version: OpenJDK Runtime Environment JBR-17.0.4.1+7-469.62-jcef (17.0.4.1+7) (build 17.0.4.1+7-b469.62)
# Java VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM JBR-17.0.4.1+7-469.62-jcef (17.0.4.1+7-b469.62, mixed mode, tiered, compressed oops, compressed class ptrs, g1 gc, windows-amd64)
# Problematic frame:
# J 24529 c2 net.jpountz.lz4.LZ4UnsafeUtils.readIntEquals([BII)Z (19 bytes) @ 0x0000000016ab2bd6 [0x0000000016ab2b00+0x00000000000000d6]
#
# No core dump will be written. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/JBR
#

---------------  S U M M A R Y ------------

Command Line: exit -Xms128m -Xmx2000m -XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=512m -XX:+IgnoreUnrecognizedVMOptions -XX:+UseG1GC -XX:SoftRefLRUPolicyMSPerMB=50 -XX:CICompilerCount=2 -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:-OmitStackTraceInFastThrow -ea -Dsun.io.useCanonCaches=false -Djdk.http.auth.tunneling.disabledSchemes="" -Djdk.attach.allowAttachSelf=true -Djdk.module.illegalAccess.silent=true -Dkotlinx.coroutines.debug=off -XX:ErrorFile=$USER_HOME/java_error_in_idea_%p.log -XX:HeapDumpPath=$USER_HOME/java_error_in_idea.hprof --add-opens=java.base/jdk.internal.org.objectweb.asm=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/jdk.internal.org.objectweb.asm.tree=ALL-UNNAMED -javaagent:E:\IDMDownload\clionCrack\ja-netfilter.jar=jetbrains -Djb.vmOptionsFile=E:\IDMDownload\clionCrack\vmoptions\clion.vmoptions -Djava.system.class.loader=com.intellij.util.lang.PathClassLoader -Didea.strict.classpath=true -Didea.vendor.name=JetBrains -Didea.paths.selector=CLion2022.2 -Didea.platform.prefix=CLion -Dsplash=true --add-opens=java.base/java.io=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.lang.reflect=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.net=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.nio=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.nio.charset=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.text=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.time=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.util.concurrent=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.util.concurrent.atomic=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/jdk.internal.vm=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/sun.nio.ch=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/sun.security.ssl=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/sun.security.util=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.desktop/java.awt=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.desktop/java.awt.dnd.peer=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.desktop/java.awt.event=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.desktop/java.awt.image=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.desktop/java.awt.peer=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.desktop/javax.swing=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.desktop/javax.swing.plaf.basic=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.desktop/javax.swing.text.html=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.desktop/sun.awt.datatransfer=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.desktop/sun.awt.image=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.desktop/sun.awt.windows=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.desktop/sun.awt=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.desktop/sun.font=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.desktop/sun.java2d=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.desktop/sun.swing=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=jdk.attach/sun.tools.attach=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.api=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=jdk.internal.jvmstat/sun.jvmstat.monitor=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=jdk.jdi/com.sun.tools.jdi=ALL-UNNAMED -Dide.native.launcher=true -XX:ErrorFile=C:\Users\stem\\java_error_in_clion64_%p.log -XX:HeapDumpPath=C:\Users\stem\\java_error_in_clion64.hprof 

Host: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-10750H CPU @ 2.60GHz, 12 cores, 15G,  Windows 10 , 64 bit Build 19041 (10.0.19041.3155)
Time: Fri Aug  4 15:29:34 2023 中国标准时间 elapsed time: 19.939526 seconds (0d 0h 0m 19s)

---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------

Current thread (0x00000001583aa750):  JavaThread "Flushing Daemon" [_thread_in_Java, id=14792, stack(0x000000015dce0000,0x000000015dde0000)]

Stack: [0x000000015dce0000,0x000000015dde0000],  sp=0x000000015ddde128,  free space=1016k
Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code)
C  0x0000000016ab2bd6


siginfo: EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005), reading address 0x000000000000074a


Register to memory mapping:

RIP=0x0000000016ab2bd6 is at entry_point+214 in (nmethod*)0x0000000016ab2990
RAX=0x0000000080e82cb1 is pointing into metadata
RBX=0x0000000080e82ce0 is pointing into metadata
RCX=0x0000000080e6dd40 is pointing into metadata
RDX=0x00000000d490fc80 is an oop: sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileAttributes 
{0x00000000d490fc80} - klass: 'sun/nio/fs/WindowsFileAttributes'
 - ---- fields (total size 8 words):
 - private final 'fileAttrs' 'I' @12  32 (20)
 - private final 'creationTime' 'J' @16  133330850343397186 (b451a742 1d9afb3)
 - private final 'lastAccessTime' 'J' @24  133355434005699997 (88c71d9d 1d9c60f)
 - private final 'lastWriteTime' 'J' @32  133355434005699997 (88c71d9d 1d9c60f)
 - private final 'size' 'J' @40  32626 (7f72 0)
 - private final 'reparseTag' 'I' @48  0
 - private final 'volSerialNumber' 'I' @52  0
 - private final 'fileIndexHigh' 'I' @56  0
 - private final 'fileIndexLow' 'I' @60  0
RSP=0x000000015ddde128 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x00000001583aa750
RBP=0x000000015ddde198 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x00000001583aa750
RSI=0x000000016b74b960 is pointing into metadata
RDI=0x000000000000074a is an unknown value
R8 =0x0 is NULL
R9 =0x0000000000003738 is an unknown value
R10=0x00007ffbbfd7ea30 jvm.dll
R11=0x0000000016ab2b00 is at entry_point+0 in (nmethod*)0x0000000016ab2990
R12=0x0 is NULL
R13=0x000000015ddde138 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x00000001583aa750
R14=0x000000015ddde250 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x00000001583aa750
R15=0x00000001583aa750 is a thread


Registers:
RAX=0x0000000080e82cb1, RBX=0x0000000080e82ce0, RCX=0x0000000080e6dd40, RDX=0x00000000d490fc80
RSP=0x000000015ddde128, RBP=0x000000015ddde198, RSI=0x000000016b74b960, RDI=0x000000000000074a
R8 =0x0000000000000000, R9 =0x0000000000003738, R10=0x00007ffbbfd7ea30, R11=0x0000000016ab2b00
R12=0x0000000000000000, R13=0x000000015ddde138, R14=0x000000015ddde250, R15=0x00000001583aa750
RIP=0x0000000016ab2bd6, EFLAGS=0x0000000000010282

Top of Stack: (sp=0x000000015ddde128)
0x000000015ddde128:   0000000006169600 0000000006169600
0x000000015ddde138:   0000000000003738 0000000000000000
0x000000015ddde148:   00000000d490fcc0 000000015ddde150
0x000000015ddde158:   0000000080e6bdc9 000000015ddde250
0x000000015ddde168:   0000000080e6dd40 0000000000000000
0x000000015ddde178:   0000000085b9c420 0000000080e6c0a8
0x000000015ddde188:   000000015ddde138 000000015ddde228
0x000000015ddde198:   000000015ddde2a0 0000000006169600
0x000000015ddde1a8:   0000000000001cf6 0000000000000008
0x000000015ddde1b8:   0000000000001fe9 0000000000000002
0x000000015ddde1c8:   000000000000099b 0000000000000041
0x000000015ddde1d8:   0000000000000001 0000000000000000
0x000000015ddde1e8:   0000000000003739 00000000d4921598
0x000000015ddde1f8:   0000000000003737 0000000000001fee
0x000000015ddde208:   0000000000003738 0000000000007ff4
0x000000015ddde218:   0000000000007ffb 0000000000008000 

Instructions: (pc=0x0000000016ab2bd6)
0x0000000016ab2ad6:   00 00 00 04 00 00 06 00 00 00 ff ff ff ff ff ff
0x0000000016ab2ae6:   ff ff 35 b0 26 64 2b f0 05 80 11 64 0f 00 00 64
0x0000000016ab2af6:   0f 64 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 89 84 24 00 90 ff
0x0000000016ab2b06:   ff 55 48 83 ec 20 4d 63 d0 48 85 d2 74 2f 46 8b
0x0000000016ab2b16:   54 12 10 4d 63 d9 46 8b 44 1a 10 b8 01 00 00 00
0x0000000016ab2b26:   45 33 db 45 3b d0 41 0f 45 c3 48 83 c4 20 5d 49
0x0000000016ab2b36:   3b a7 40 03 00 00 0f 87 1e 00 00 00 c3 49 83 c2
0x0000000016ab2b46:   10 48 8b ea 44 89 0c 24 4c 89 54 24 08 ba 5c ff
0x0000000016ab2b56:   ff ff 66 66 90 e8 a0 f7 6f ef 49 ba 35 2b ab 16
0x0000000016ab2b66:   00 00 00 00 4d 89 97 58 03 00 00 e9 8a 08 70 ef
0x0000000016ab2b76:   f4 f4 f4 f4 f4 f4 f4 f4 f4 f4 e9 fb 1f 7a ef e8
0x0000000016ab2b86:   00 00 00 00 48 83 2c 24 05 e9 0c fb 6f ef f4 f4
0x0000000016ab2b96:   f4 f4 08 34 29 85 00 00 00 00 00 98 23 85 00 00
0x0000000016ab2ba6:   00 00 e0 2c e8 80 00 00 00 00 40 b6 e7 80 00 00
0x0000000016ab2bb6:   00 00 40 99 9e 57 00 00 00 00 ff 03 00 d2 02 00
0x0000000016ab2bc6:   00 00 01 00 01 03 01 00 00 02 00 00 00 00 09 02
0x0000000016ab2bd6:   0b 0f 00 00 04 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 04 02 01
0x0000000016ab2be6:   02 00 01 00 00 44 14 03 06 1a 23 00 00 00 00 00
0x0000000016ab2bf6:   00 00 ff ff ff ff 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
0x0000000016ab2c06:   00 00 60 00 00 00 2c 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
0x0000000016ab2c16:   00 00 99 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
0x0000000016ab2c26:   00 00 01 01 01 02 01 03 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
0x0000000016ab2c36:   00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
0x0000000016ab2c46:   00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
0x0000000016ab2c56:   00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
0x0000000016ab2c66:   00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
0x0000000016ab2c76:   00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 06 00 00 00 00 00
0x0000000016ab2c86:   00 00 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 30 d5 b7 bf fb 7f
0x0000000016ab2c96:   00 00 02 00 00 00 68 02 00 00 58 01 00 00 0c 00
0x0000000016ab2ca6:   00 00 e8 01 00 00 04 00 00 00 00 2e ab 16 00 00
0x0000000016ab2cb6:   00 00 78 2e ab 16 00 00 00 00 00 2e ab 16 00 00
0x0000000016ab2cc6:   00 00 f8 2e ab 16 00 00 00 00 e8 2d ab 16 00 00 


Stack slot to memory mapping:
stack at sp + 0 slots: 0x0000000006169600 is at code_begin+1376 in an Interpreter codelet
return entry points  [0x00000000061690a0, 0x0000000006169b80]  2784 bytes
stack at sp + 1 slots: 0x0000000006169600 is at code_begin+1376 in an Interpreter codelet
return entry points  [0x00000000061690a0, 0x0000000006169b80]  2784 bytes
stack at sp + 2 slots: 0x0000000000003738 is an unknown value
stack at sp + 3 slots: 0x0 is NULL
stack at sp + 4 slots: 0x00000000d490fcc0 is an oop: [B 
{0x00000000d490fcc0} - klass: {type array byte}
 - length: 32768
stack at sp + 5 slots: 0x000000015ddde150 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x00000001583aa750
stack at sp + 6 slots: 0x0000000080e6bdc9 is pointing into metadata
stack at sp + 7 slots: 0x000000015ddde250 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x00000001583aa750

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[Constant Pool (empty)]

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

[MachCode]
  0x0000000016ab2b00: 8984 2400 | 90ff ff55 | 4883 ec20 | 4d63 d048 | 85d2 742f | 468b 5412 | 104d 63d9 | 468b 441a 
  0x0000000016ab2b20: 10b8 0100 | 0000 4533 | db45 3bd0 | 410f 45c3 | 4883 c420 | 5d49 3ba7 | 4003 0000 | 0f87 1e00 
  0x0000000016ab2b40: 0000 c349 | 83c2 1048 | 8bea 4489 | 0c24 4c89 | 5424 08ba | 5cff ffff | 6666 90e8 | a0f7 6fef 
  0x0000000016ab2b60: 49ba 352b | ab16 0000 | 0000 4d89 | 9758 0300 | 00e9 8a08 | 70ef f4f4 | f4f4 f4f4 | f4f4 f4f4 
  0x0000000016ab2b80: e9fb 1f7a | efe8 0000 | 0000 4883 | 2c24 05e9 | 0cfb 6fef | f4f4 f4f4 
[/MachCode]
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------




com.intellij.diagnostic.JBRCrash
```

And the time of the crash is random, it may be that the program was just opened, or it may be that the software is standby in the background.I just use clion to do some very basic C++ algorithm problems, such as threads, double pointers, etc., so I'm sure I can rule out that it's caused by the program

also，my VisualStudio2023 is always crashes too。 i think maybe there is something worng with my javaJDK？ i dont know。 by the way，sorry for my bad english。

I removed VS and Clion and also reinstalled，but it didnt work。At the same time, my Android studio will crash too。

```
-Xms128m
-Xmx2000m
-XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=512m
-XX:+IgnoreUnrecognizedVMOptions
-XX:+UseG1GC
-XX:SoftRefLRUPolicyMSPerMB=50
-XX:CICompilerCount=2
-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError
-XX:-OmitStackTraceInFastThrow
-ea
-Dsun.io.useCanonCaches=false
-Djdk.http.auth.tunneling.disabledSchemes=""
-Djdk.attach.allowAttachSelf=true
-Djdk.module.illegalAccess.silent=true
-Dkotlinx.coroutines.debug=off
-XX:ErrorFile=$USER_HOME/java_error_in_idea_%p.log
-XX:HeapDumpPath=$USER_HOME/java_error_in_idea.hprof

--add-opens=java.base/jdk.internal.org.objectweb.asm=ALL-UNNAMED
--add-opens=java.base/jdk.internal.org.objectweb.asm.tree=ALL-UNNAMED

-javaagent:E:\IDMDownload\clionCrack\ja-netfilter.jar=jetbrains
```

here is my 'E:\IDMDownload\clionCrack\vmoptions\clion.vmoptions' files content.I don't think it has much to do with the running file.And i am sorry that, I have deleted the running file that reported the error before, and reinstalled the software again, and I will add the corresponding run file when I crash again.

Oh, my Clion2022.2 crash again. Here is my running code:

```
//
// Created by stem on 2023/8/15.
//
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <winsock2.h>

#define BUF_SIZE 1024

struct DataPack
{
    int num;
    char mark;
    std::string message;
};

//client
int main()
{
    WSADATA wsaData;
    if (WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,2),&wsaData) != 0 )
    {
        std::cout << "WSAStartup error" << std::endl;
    }
    DataPack dataPack;
//    memset(&dataPack,0,sizeof(dataPack));
    int recvLength;
    char * leftover;
    int server_socket = socket(PF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0);
    sockaddr_in server_addr;
    int server_addr_size = sizeof(server_addr);
    memset(&server_addr,0,server_addr_size);
    server_addr.sin_family = PF_INET;
    server_addr.sin_port = htons(atoi("5234"));
    server_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");

    if( connect(server_socket,(sockaddr *)&server_addr,server_addr_size) == SOCKET_ERROR) std::cout << "connect error" << std::endl;
    else std::cout << "connect successfully" << std::endl;
//---------------------------connect
    recvLength =  recv(server_socket,(char*)&dataPack,BUF_SIZE,0);
    std::cout << "dataPack.message = " << dataPack.message << std::endl;
    int num = 0;
    std::cout << "please input numbers :" ;
    std::cin >> num;
    dataPack.num = num;
    send(server_socket,(char *)&dataPack, sizeof(dataPack) ,0);

    for(int i = 0; i < num ; ++i)
    {
        std::cout << "your number [" << i << "]is :";
        std::cin >> dataPack.num;
        send(server_socket,(char*)&dataPack, sizeof(dataPack), 0);
    }

    std::cout << "your mark is :";
    std::cin >> dataPack.mark;
    send(server_socket,(char*)&dataPack,sizeof(dataPack) , 0);

    recvLength = recv(server_socket,(char *)&dataPack,BUF_SIZE,0);
    std::cout << "result is :" << dataPack.num;
    closesocket(server_socket);
    WSACleanup();
}
```

Comment: You need to show us the code that crashes. With this crash report, we can't do much (It's neither related to VS nor C++)

Comment: @PMF @LittleShark I am so sorry, but the path 
`E:\IDMDownload\clionCrack\vmoptions\clion.vmoptions`
looks so suspicious :D